# Very slow innodb operations

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I have php script for comparing url to our db urls and saving only new ones. The problem is that each step of this script is taking very long (more than ~10 minutes total). Here's the steps:

```
$query = sprintf("DELETE FROM %s ; ", $DB ['compare_result_table']);

$query = sprintf("LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' IGNORE INTO TABLE %s
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        ENCLOSED BY \"'\"
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        (domain, url_value)",
      $real_out_path, $DB["compare_result_table"]);

$query = sprintf(" INSERT INTO %s SELECT domain 
        FROM %s ;", $DB ['compare_url_table'], 'domain_data' );

$query = sprintf("DELETE a.*
              FROM %s a INNER JOIN %s b using (domain);",
         $DB["compare_result_table"], $DB ['compare_url_table']);
```

Here's the tables description:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cmp_url;
CREATE TABLE cmp_url
(
    domain varchar(255),
    index (domain)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cmp_result;
CREATE TABLE cmp_result
(
    domain varchar(255),
    url_value varchar(4096),
    index (domain)

);
```

Everytime I call show PROCESSLIST I see that every step (excluding, maybe data load from file) is taking very long. The domain_data table, that contains our domains to compare is 600 000 records now. The bigger it becomes, the slower are all the steps.

Here's some options I changed in my.cnf:

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 360
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
binlog_format=mixed
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
```

But it doesnt change anything. How can I solve that issue? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you deleting with an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: try executing a shell script from PHP to mysql server, is more faster execute shell scripts than using mysql connectors, consider the time to transfer the file too, with shell script the transfer is over the network.

Comment: I thought it would be faster than subquery. Or what method should I use. Also, deleting and inserting into cmp_url table tooks very long.

Comment: @randiel,I think thats database issue

Comment: try a tunning of your database! how is the schema size?

Comment: @randiel, i tried to tuned it, there are some options in the post

Comment: pusblish a new question about mariadb tunning.

Comment: A table with just one column?  Why?

Comment: Are you "replacing" the entire table(s)?  Or is the `LOAD` a list of "changes"?  Either of those can be done much faster; I need to know the intent before discussion further.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, I'am clearing tables and the filling the again by new data.

Answer (score 0):

For completely replacing a table:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
LOAD (or whatever) into new.
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Fast.  Zero downtime.